How to estimate group-time average treatment effects with diff-in-diff staggered treatment adoption
I want to estimate how floodings changes unemployment rate in various countries between 2005-2020. i therefore have multiple treatments and time periods. when i run this code to estimate the aggreagate group-time average treatment effects:
staggdidreg1 <- att_gt(
  yname = "unemployment_rate",      # Outcome variable
  tname = "start_year",             # Time variable
  idname = "id",                    # ID variable
  gname = "treatment_time",       # First treatment period variable
  control_group = "nevertreated",  # Set the comparison group as "not yet treated"
  data = unemploymentnationalallfloods,  # Data frame
  xformla = NULL,                   # Covariates (set to NULL for default)
  allow_unbalanced_panel = TRUE     # Allow unbalanced panel data
)

I get this error message:
Error in pre_process_did(yname = yname, tname = tname, idname = idname,  : 
  There is no available never-treated group
In addition: Warning message:
In pre_process_did(yname = yname, tname = tname, idname = idname,  :
  dropped 32 rows from original data due to missing data 

how do i solve this problem?

Please use minimal reproducible examples others can run using copy & paste. Show desired output entirely. Use dput() for data & specify all non-base packages with library(). Don't embed pictures for data or code, use indented code blocks instead.
